# Importing txt file with fopen on PHP bring space between letters

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, character, fopen

I'm importing and reading a TXT file with PHP using fopen. But between each letter on TXT file brings one strange character, and I tried to find some solutions here but I coudn't find.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
mysqli_query($sConn,"DELETE FROM cnpjPrincipal");
$myfile = fopen("Arquivos/1.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$nLine = 0;
//*************************************************************************************//
while(!feof($myfile)&&$nLine<5){
    $sLine = fgets($myfile);
    if(substr($sLine, 1, 1)=="1"){
        $nLine += 1;
        echo "Position 1:   '".fCutString($sLine, 0, 1)."' <br/>";
        echo "Position 2:   '".fCutString($sLine, 1, 1)."' <br/>";
        echo "Position 3:   '".fCutString($sLine, 2, 1)."' <br/>";
        echo "Position 4:   '".fCutString($sLine, 3, 14)."' <br/>";
        echo "Position 18:  '".fCutString($sLine, 17, 1)."' <br/>";
        echo "Position 19:  '".fCutString($sLine, 18, 150)."' <br/>";
        echo "Position 169: '".fCutString($sLine, 168, 55)."'<br /><br />";
        echo $sLine."<br /><br />";
        echo mb_detect_encoding($sLine)."<br /><br />";
    }
}
//*************************************************************************************//
fclose($myfile);
//*************************************************************************************//
function fCutString($sString, $nStart, $nEnd){
    return substr($sString, $nStart, $nEnd);
};
?>
```

Then I tried to use:

```
<?php
// Solution 1
$sLine = mb_convert_encoding(fgets($myfile),mb_detect_encoding(fgets($myfile, mb_detect_order(), true)),"UTF-8");
// Solution 2
$sLine = iconv(mb_detect_encoding(fgets($myfile), mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", fgets($myfile));
// Solution 3
$sLine = utf8_encode(fgets($myfile));
?>
```

But any solution worked.
On HTML brings:

```
Position 1: ''
Position 2: '1'
Position 3: ''
Position 4: 'F 01772'
Position 18: '2'
Position 19: '210001401ALEXANDRE TABORDA GOULART '
Position 169: ' '

Full Line: 1F 017722210001401ALEXANDRE TABORDA GOULART 042019032263 2135199704155819100AVENIDA DR CARLOS BARBOSA 233 ANDAR 1 AZENHA 90880001RS8801PORTO ALEGRE 51 34444882 50000000000000000182007070120161231N F

ASCII
```

When I open the HTML generated, open like that:
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeGAp.png)

I put a function to inform the encoding, that shows me that is ASCII.
I get the file from the government and I'm trying to split the information by position, but as I have strange characters between the letters bring wrong information to me. The TXT file cames as UNICODE.
Somebody already tried to fix something like that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, cause if I have to change something I only change the function. This is a small part of the code. The file has 1200 characters each line... something like 20 files with 5gb each one.

Comment: Could you share the file or at least a sample of it by uploading it somewhere? I have a suspicion the file you've saved is using UTF-16 which uses 2 bytes for each character and would explain why things like substr which were designed to work with ASCII(1 byte per character) produces unexpected output.

Comment: Hello Scragar, yes... Please, use the link: http://estruturaonline.com.br/TaxCompliance/Consulta/Arquivos/Example.txt OR http://estruturaonline.com.br/TaxCompliance/Consulta/Arquivos/Example.zip

Comment: You can check the result by opening the link http://estruturaonline.com.br/TaxCompliance/Consulta/OpenFile.php

Comment: That file is in UTF-16LE, try converting it to UTF8 using `$sLine = iconv('UTF-16LE' , 'UTF-8' , $sLine);` and see if that improves things.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't worked! I tried to change even the txt file to another encoding, but the result was the same...

Comment: The strange thing is that when I change the txt file to UTF8 my php can't read the txt file

Comment: Ok, I finished it! I change the big txt file...

Comment: Please provide the hex for part of a line so that we can diagnose what is going on.  See `bin2hex()`.